# Managing partials and components in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a project that utilizes a dashboard with many different widgets.  These widgets are primarily charts.  The widgets will interact with many different models and can be called in many different pages and dashboards.  Should I create one universal Widget controller and model that handles all of these widgets, or should these widgets be specific to each model?  I was thinking the one Widget approach would be better to keep all of the widgets together.  If i were to go this route though is there a way I can have the view that calls a partial(widget) run a specific controller method?

For example, I have a show.html.erb file that calls /widget/_orders.html.erb.  Whenever this _orders.html.erb partial is called I want it work off of data provided by the 'order' method in the widget_controller.rb.  Is there a way to do this, or possibly a better?

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in [cells](https://github.com/apotonick/cells) project.